# Class function return different results

Tags: python, class, output

I have 2 different ways to set up a python class. One that automaticly runs the class function, and one that you need to run manually.

Manually running function:

```
class testclass:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value

   def validator(self):
      data = self.value[0] + self.value[1]
      data = int(data)
      return data
theClass = testclass('123456')
print(theClass.validator())
```

This prints "12"

Automaticly running the function:

```
class testclass:
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      self.validator()

   def validator(self):
      data = self.value[0] + self.value[1]
      data = int(data)
      return data
theClass = testclass('123456')
print(theClass)
```

this prints "<**main**.testclass object at 0x011C72B0>"

How can i run the class function automaticly, and still get 12 as print output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second version you are calling the `validator` function in `__init__`, but not returning the value that `validator` is returning. The problem is that `__init__` is not able to return anything but `None`. What you can do is to assign the value to an instance variable:

```
class testclass:
  value = 0
  def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value
      self.value = self.validator()

  def validator(self):
      data = self.value[0] + self.value[1]
      data = int(data)
      return data
theClass = testclass('123456')
print(theClass.value)
```

Ouptut:

```
12
```

Answer (score 1):

In your automatic example, you are not calling 'theClass'. Any function calls need `()`.
You can rename your automatic `validator` the `__call__` and call it as `theClass()`.

See more at [https://www.journaldev.com/22761/python-callable-**call**](https://www.journaldev.com/22761/python-callable-__call__)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to print the output value, and not use it as a variable, you can define `__str__` as part of your class.

```
class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return self.validator()

    def validator(self):
        data = self.value[0] + self.value[1]
        data = int(data)
        return data

>>> theClass = testclass('123456')
>>> print(theClass)
12
```

If you want to use it as a variable, such as `theClass + 5`, then using a custom class is not the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Print inside the `validator` function:

```
class TestClass:  # sticking to more Pythonic naming conventions
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.validator()

    def validator(self):
        print(int(self.value[0] + self.value[1]))
```

This will automatically print validation output whenever an instance is created:

```
>>> the_class = TestClass('123456')
12
```